# R: Coloring plots

Tags: r, colors, plot

I have some data that I want to plot (e.g. `plot(x,y)`) but I have some *criteria that I want to color by* depending on the values in vector `z` which looks like `c(1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, NA ,0 ,0, .....)` etc.

Is there some way I can choose what color the `1`'s are going to be and what color the `0`'s are going to be?

Thanks

Comment: What color do you want the NAs to be?

Comment: Haven't decided but for argument sake lets say black. what if I don't want them to show up?

Comment: create a vector of same length with the colors at the same position (for example with ifelse) and use it in the plot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to get a vector of colors as long as the `x` and `y` vectors, for example as follows:

```
z[is.na(z)] = 2
zcol = c("red", "blue", "black")[z + 1]
```

Then you can simply do:

```
plot(x, y, col=zcol)
```

Comment: I like this succinct answer:)

Answer (score 4):

I know this has already been answered but here is some **very** intuitive code with a plot for reference.

```
#Let's create some fictional data 
x = rbinom(100,1,.5)
x[round(runif(10)*100)] = NA

#Assign colors to 1's and 0's
colors = rep(NA,length(x))
colors[x==1] = "blue"
colors[x==0] = "red" 

#Plot the vector x
plot(x,bg=colors,pch=21)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I am missing something, but I think you want:

```
plot(x,y,col=ifelse(z==0,'zerocolour','onecolour'))
```

where you replace the two colours with `red` and `blue` or whatever.

I don't think the `NA` will be plotted, so you don't have to worry about those.

For more colours, you could create a little mapping `data.frame` with the unique values of `z`, and then merge `z` with the `data.frame`. Here is an example with two colours:

```
map<-data.frame(z=c(0,1),col=c('red','blue'))
plot(x,y,col=merge(z,map)$col)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the ggplot2 package

```
require(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), y = c(2, 3, 4, 6, 7), z = c(1, 0 , 1, 0 , NA))
df$z[is.na(df$z)] = 2
ggplot(df, aes(x, y, color = as.factor(z))) + geom_point()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can supply vector of colors to argument `col=` and then use z to select colors. Used `paste()` to convert NA to character and then `as.factor()` to interpret those characters as 1, 2 and 3.

```
x<-c(1,2,3,4,5)
y<-c(1,2,3,4,5)
z<-c(1,0,NA,1,1)
plot(x,y,col=c("red","green",'black')[as.factor(paste(z))],pch=19,cex=3)

str(as.factor(paste(z)))
Factor w/ 3 levels "0","1","NA": 2 1 3 2 2
```